# I changed MySQL port in XAMPP, now how do I listen to the new port?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed the latest XAMPP with MySQL version 14.14 Distrib 5.6.21, the problem is in my computer, I already have a MySQL database installed by other program that I am using.

So I configure the XAMPP MySQL port to 3307 (default is 3306) inside the `my.ini` file. However, now my localhost/phpmyadmin seems to read the database installed by the other program, not the one in XAMPP, and also when I test using some PHP files, it shows that I am connected to the database even though XAMPP is turned off (XAMPP MySQL also disconnected).

How do I change the setting of my PHPMyAdmin and localhost to connect to the MySQL port 3307?

I don't understand how all these ports and the database work.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Goto `xampp>phpMyAdmin` Directory.

Find the `config.inc.php` file.

Now change this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

To

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much for your answer, it works, but i actually hope for some elaboration or any reference where I can study on more, such as what number of ports are available and can be used for mysql ? also how does port 3307 differ from the default port 3306 ? thx a lot anyway.

Comment: Here is the ports list
http://www.iss.net/security_center/advice/Exploits/Ports/default.htm

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother once again, I just realized when I open localhost, my localhost is not connected to the new mysql port 3307, how do I set localhost to connect to the port 3307 ? thx.

Comment: nvm, I solved it, change mysqli default port in the php.ini file, thx!

Comment: You need 127.0.0.1:port_number when you change your http port from default which is 80 to one another !!!

Comment: Why the need to restart the server?

Comment: No need to restart server if you make changes only in config.inc.php

Answer (score 6):

To configure phpMyAdmin to connect to a different port from the default, edit your `config.inc.php` file and add a line like:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';`

(of course substituting any port number as needed). You can also see the [official documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_port).

Answer (score 4):

First open the following path:

```
  C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
```

Add the following string in config.inc.php file.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, I just added my port code to:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3308';`

Answer (score 0):

Add below line under phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = port number;
```

in my case the port number is `8111`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307'; /* change port is here */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

Answer (score 0):

To configure PHPMyAdmin to connect to MySQL on port 3307:

1. Open the config.inc.php file in the PHPMyAdmin directory :

   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php
2. Find the line containing $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] and set it to 'localhost:3307':
   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3307';`
3. Ensure the port is set correctly in $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']:
   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';`
4. Save the file.
   After making these changes, PHPMyAdmin should connect to the MySQL database on port 3307.

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the previous answers?