# How to use xammp and mysql server at same time

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to connect my database with PHPStorm. The problem is that when i run mysql at xampp

[image]

I get the following error

[image]

because my mysql server is down

[image]

but if i try to run both mysql server and xampp i get the following error

[image]

I am really new to php and mysql so sorry for the question

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems like mysql is running but you've supplied the wrong credentials.

Comment: Why do you need two mysql instances running? If you do for whatever reason, one of them needs to be assigned to a port other than `3306`.

Comment: However that is going to get extremely confusing managing databases on your localhost very quickly, and is probably not a good idea to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `default port number:3306` to another valid port number for one of mysql instance.

please take a look here [how to change the default port of MySQL in xammp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807338/i-changed-mysql-port-in-xampp-now-how-do-i-listen-to-the-new-port)